# How to create flow in salesforce?

Tags: visual-workflow

I m trying to create a new flow in Salesforce customization part, but I'm getting this error

> "You must enable or download Adobe Flash Player version 10.2.0 or later to use this feature. Please download it here"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Salesforce visual workflow designer uses flash! You must install flash on your web browser.

See https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ to download

Best is to use Google chrome as it includes flash player on its own.

Answer (score 3):

In the last version of plugin "Flash Player", users must to provide right to run it. Usually it is simply - just click on `<object>` of plug-in

Is SF case - this tag is hidden. You need to display this block - that's it!

In to chrome DevTool - in the dom-tree call "Ctrl + F" and find `#flashContent` tag, and switch-off css property `display: none`. So, now you should to see the message/button "if you want to start Flash Player..."

I mention - you need to pass this procedure only once ( after reload browser - plugin should be in auto-run mode )

Comment: I think the preferred way to do this to add an exception to [allow Flash content on your Salesforce domain](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164195/new-flow-gives-blank-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1).